# Javascript global variable not working & more

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

### I have a few questions about the code below:

- I define a global variable called iMax on line 11. It doesn't work if I try to call it on line 17 though. Why?[ANSWERED]
- This script won't work in web browsers due to node modules 'cheerio' and 'request' but it works in the local command prompt. Is there any way I can have another javascript that *does* run in a webpage to share variables with and execute this javascript to run outisde of the webpage (locally)? The two javascripts will be in the same directory. [UNANSWERED]
- When I remove 'urls = [];' from line 3, oddly enough I get an error that says:
   
  *request('http://forum.blockland.us/index.php?action=profile;u=137487;sa=showPosts'

  SyntaxError: Unexpected token (*


  which makes no sense to me because 'urls = [];' has no purpose in the code. Any ideas why this happens? [ANSWERED]

-

```
1    var request = require('request'),
2       cheerio = require('cheerio'),
3       urls = [];
4    
5       
6    request('http://forum.blockland.us/index.php?action=profile;u=137487;sa=showPosts', function(err, resp, body){
7       if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
8           var $ = cheerio.load(body);
9           $('b:contains(...)', 'tr.catbg3').each(function(){
10              totalPages = $(this).next().text();
11              iMax = (totalPages - 1) * 15;
12          });
13      }
14    });
15    
16    
17    for(i = 0; i <= iMax; i += 15)
18    {
19      console.log(i);
20    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't asynchronous JavaScript be a problem?

Comment: While declared variables are created before any code is executed, implicit global variables don't exist until the expression that creates them is executed. So *iMax* isn't created until the request returns, but you attempt to access it immediately after calling *request*.

Comment: Please stick to one question per post.  The answers to this are getting to be quite a mess.

Comment: Yep I see your point (and I originally intended to have numbers for each question to be a little more organized). This is my first question posted on this forum so I don't know the ropes yet. I come from a forum where even double posting is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

Declare  var iMax ={A default value your cool with } ; at the top.

Right now  you're actually calling that for loop before iMax is actually declared.

Answer (score 1):

"When all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail". You're not using the correct tech in the correct ways to achieve your goals.

The JavaScript running in the browser is running on the client's sandbox, so setting global variables on the server which would then run a node.js instance is probably impractical.

What you probably need is a lightweight web server... Node can do this for you if you wish and swallow a POST back. A simple HTTP server is one of the first Node.js tutorials. Then you can do what you wish with the POST'ed information.

Really though, a simple web-server with a scripting module which can pass off the information and run up node.js is probably the easiest way of doing this sustainably.

The other posters are correct, beware of multiple statements on a single line in JavaScript, it's considered bad practice.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a 'simple HTTP server' Node.js tutorial. I'm honestly very unfamiliar with the things you mentioned (I started writing javascript 3 days ago haha)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably define the variable before calling request: `var iMax;` inside the global scope or use `window.iMax = (totalPages - 1) * 15;`. But in fact you should use the for-loop in the request-function, because otherwise it could be needless, if you don't have set `iMax`.

Comment: Inserting the for-loop between the stuff on line 13 and 14 works. Awesome. Now I just need answers to the other 2 questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the line with `urls = [];` you actually remove the semicolon sign `;` as well.

That makes the next line a declaration line, meaning that everything after the line `cheerio = require('cheerio'),` becomes another declaration of a variable. Bad bad syntax error.

So, do remove the line `urls = [];` but replace the comma with a semicolon so that you have `cheerio = require('cheerio');`